# g++ - Cant link to static library built with VS2012

Tags: c++, windows, linker, g++, static-linking

I built a static library (.lib) with VS2012. I wrote a test program by including my header and then tried to link it with the .lib file with g++

`g++ Test.cpp Gray.lib -o test.exe`

(All files are in the same directory)

And I'm getting `undefined reference to` errors on functions in my library. What do I do? I already searched for many answers, those didn't help.

Comment: Name decoration is different between the compilers you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that without resorting to hacks, because name mangling is different between compilers you want to use. The most straigforward way is to complile your library for g++ natively.